# HTML5 editor lost format while pasting from microsoft word

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html

I am doing a project in asp.net mvc3 c#. Based on the client requirement I need to implement HTML5 editor.

While searching the net I got Aloha Editor but while pasting from Microsoft Word the editor didn't show the actual format (missing color, image etc).

Is there is any alternative HTML5 editor that will solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Most editors strip out Microsoft Word's HTML code because MS does all kinds of crazy things in Word which cause issues when trying to display as a normal HTML document.

A great new HTML 5 editor is the one from Wijmo, which is a jQuery UI plugin (http://wijmo.com/demo/v2/#editor|overview).  In the online demo, you can paste in text copied from Word and flip to the source view to see how bad the HTML is.  You might not have any problems, it all depends on what you've done in your document.

Answer (score 0):

There are many editor, some are free others need license. In this page you can find a list of free editor.
http://sixrevisions.com/user-interface/rich-text-editors-for-2010-and-beyond/

There is also the Telerik editor that support word documents, but it's not for free for commercial use.
http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/editor.aspx